# Finding a good Lyapunov function for $ \{ x'= y , y'= -4 x + 5x^3 - x^5 \}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

For the system:

$$\begin{cases}x'= y \\y'= -4 x + 5x^3 - x^5 \end{cases} $$

I am trying to determine the stability of $(x,y)=(0,0)$ by **means of a Lyapunov function.** I am trying to find a good one, the regular $V(x,y)=ax^2 + by^2$ does not help me as I get odd-powered terms and products of $x$ and $y$ that do not cancel. Specifically:
$$ \dot{V}(x,y) = 2axy + b xy(-1+5x^2-x^4)$$
Does someone have a better suggestion, what is the general approach in finding such a function for a given problem? I want to somehow use the fact that these odd powers of $x$ and $y$ appear in this system of equations, I haven't figured out how to do this in an effective manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

The dynamical system has an integral which is

$$
\frac 12 y^2+\frac{x^6}{6}-\frac{5 x^4}{4}+2 x^2=C
$$

Studying the level curves we have the following graphics

[image]

and for $0 < C < 0.915$ we have closed level curves around the origin characterizing a center.

Comment: If I use this function as a Lyapunov function I get that $\dot{V}=0$ which means we have a stable solution. This corresponds with the other explanation by Hans and your level curves. Funny how this is a conservative system.

Answer (score 2):

This is a conservative system, since it's equivalent to
$$
x'' = -4x + 5x^3 - x^5 = -V'(x)
,
$$
with the potential
$$
V(x) = 2x^2 - \tfrac54 x^4 + \tfrac16 x^6
.
$$
So $H(x,y)=\tfrac12 y^2 + V(x)$ is a constant of motion, and the trajectories follow the level curves of $H$, which near the origin look like ellipses $2 x^2 + \tfrac12 y^2 = C$. This means that the origin is neutrally stable (i.e., stable but not asymptotically stable).

Compare the two plots (on Wolfram Alpha):

- [Phase portrait](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7By,-4x%2B5x%5E3-x%5E5%7D,x%3D-2..2,y%3D-2..2)
- [Level curves](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour+plot+2x%5E2-5x%5E4%2F4%2Bx%5E6%2F6%2By%5E2%2F6,x%3D-2..2,y%3D-2..2)